# What is the number of connected components in a graph based on the given condition?

Tags: graph-theory

#### Let $G$ be a graph with 100 vertices numbered from 1 to 100. The vertices $i$ and $j$ are adjacent if $|i-j|=8$   or   $|i-j|=12$. What is the number of connected components in the graph $G$ ?

I have gotta feeling like the answer must be GCD of the two (8 and 12). Not sure about it.

*PS : The problem may be a possible duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139645/finding-a-formula-for-the-number-of-connected-components-in-a-graph) . I tried to understand but found it difficult to grasp. Solution provided in more basic and crude way will be helpful.*

Many Thanks !!

Comment: Suggestion: start with vertex $1$ then find some vertices adjacent to $1$, then some adjacent to these, and so on until you are convinced there are no more.  This will give you one connected component, but you should find that it is not the whole graph.  What do you notice about the vertices in this component?  *Hint*: you are right, the gcd has something to do with it.

Comment: If there is a path between $i$ and $j$ consider the difference $i - j$ and in term of $8$ and $12$.

Comment: I started with 1 and it grew something like 1,5,9,13,17, 21 upto 97. This pattern makes me think that other connected components must be 2,6,10,14 upto 98; and so forth. Because the difference of the consecutive terms is 4, hence 4 different sequences (connected components) will be there. Wow !! But now I am in search of some mathematical proof. As you suggested me that GCD has something to do, if I had 12 and 21, there would be 3 connected components.

Answer (score 1):

Let  $V=\lbrace 1,2,3, \ldots ,100\rbrace$.

**Claim.** If $x$ and $x+4$ are both in $V$, then $x$ and $x+4$
are in the same connected component.

**Proof of claim.** If $x\leq 100-12$, then the following are in
the same connected component : $x,x+12,(x+12)-8=x+4$. If $100-12 < x$, then
the following are in the same connected component : $x+4,(x+4)-12,(x+4)-12+8=x$.

It follows easily from the claim (and a little more work in the other direction) that the components are in fact
the residue classes modulo 4. Count them.